# Disinfecting N95 for reuse using steam

Tags: ppe

I'm trying to find good ways to disinfect and reuse N95 respirators at home. From this article https://www.webmd.com/lung/news/20200709/study-sterilize-n95-masks-with-a-microwave it's apparently possible to disinfect in a microwave, using steam to kill viruses. My question is, would a food steamer also work?

Comment: See the link to the duplicate question. Steam will render the mask ineffective.